# Problemas ao converter Session para Classe em C#

Tags: c#, .net, classes, session, cast

Tenho a seguinte variável

```
List<MyFile> xmlDisponivel = new List<MyFile>();
```

Essa variável é uma lista da seguinte classe

```
public class MyFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Em um processo eu salvo a lista que atribui a essa variável em uma session

```
Session.Add("XmlDisponivel", xmlDisponivel);
```

Em outro processo quando vou tentar pegar essas informações da session e passar pra minha variável do tipo `List<MyFile>` sempre vem null mesmo que tenha informações na lista.

Conforme print abaixo, tenho umas lista de 400 arquivos, mas quando tento fazer a conversão da session para minha variável, sempre vem null.

[image: Watch1]

Como resolver, alguma idéia?

Comment: E como você está fazendo o Cast da `Session` pra `List`? [Edita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/185640/edit) sua pergunta pra gente ver :)

Comment: `var lista = (List<MyFile>) Session["XmlDisponivel"];` ?

Comment: @OnoSendai ele mostra no print que a conversão não dá certo.

Comment: @jbueno `obj as type` != `(type) obj`. O operador `as` apenas considera referência e *boxing/unboxing*.

Comment: Ao invés de setar assim: `Session.Add("XmlDisponivel", xmlDisponivel);`, se setar assim: `Session["XmlDisponivel"] = xmlDisponivel` também não funciona?

Comment: @OnoSendai Funcionou perfeitamente, obg!! Obg a tds que tentaram ajudar!

Comment: @WellitonMeneguim Sempre um prazer ajudar! Uma sugestão - crie uma resposta descrevendo sua solução, e marque-a como tal. Assim você ajuda futuros visitantes do site. =)

Answer (score -1):

```
var lista = (List<MyFile>) Session["XmlDisponivel"];
```

Comment: Renato, recomendo colocar uma explicação para deixar a resposta mais clara e o usuario entender o porque ele deve usar a solução apresentada.